# Why does join function does not return expected string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does following code not output "John White", but outputs: "WJohnhJohniJohntJohne"

```
name = 'John Black'
print(name[:len(name)-6].join("White"))
```

What I want to do is "cut" the string from beginning to 6.th letter from the end, like "John"
And join the second name, "White" to it.

Output should be "John White"
Why does it not work?

Comment: because join uses the seperator ("John") to join together the elements of the iterable ("White"), just add the two strings together or use a form of string formatting

Comment: Because your expectation was wrong. It does work, you need to double-check what [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) does.

Comment: Please read the documentation on join, which is a string method `help(''.join)`

Comment: Not every routine/function/method/operator/keyword has a tag. Please choose tags from a list & read their wikis. Tag [tag:join] is for the relational DB operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object on which `join()` acts is the delimiter that is used as a glue between all the elements in the iterable of the `join` argument. A typical use case would be: `delimiter.join(list)`, such as `':'.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` which gives `a:b:c`. For more information, [see the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

It appears that you actually would like to *concatenate* strings, i.e.

```
name = 'John Black'
print(name[:len(name)-6] + 'White')  # note that the space is not included
```